# Is it possible to join a table valued function and another table with parameters

Tags: sql-server-2005

Quick background for those interested,

I have a master detail table(options date), about 20 details for each master record. Our oltp system that is saving the data was doing 21 inserts for each new piece of information we saved. This was killing the server, so I'm trying to get this working by substituting comma separated values for the details table. Everything seems to be working, except I can figure out how to get the details table back. I'm trying to use table valued functions, and it's not quite working.

I'd like to call something like

```
Select Top 100 *
FROM dbo.fn_MarketDataDetails (MarketDataMasterID) mdd
INNER JOIN MarketDataMaster mdm on mdm.MarketDataMasterID = mdd.MarketDataMasterID
```

Clearly, that just doesn't compile.

I can run

```
Select Top 100 *
FROM dbo.fn_MarketDataDetails (15425) // Assuming 15425 is a valid MarketDataMasterID
```

And I get back a table that looks like my old details table.

Is this even possible? Am I making any sense?

Comment: It's not clear to me where you're doing this - in CLR or TSQL?

Comment: TSQL. If I read in the Master Record I can easily do this in C#, but I'd like to do it in TSQL if possible.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The APPLY operator should do the trick:

```
SELECT *
 from MarketDataMaster
 cross apply dbo.fn_MarketDataDetails (MarketDataMasterID)
```

This essentially calls the function once per row returned from MarketDataMaster.
"cross apply" works like an inner join, in that only rows for which data is returned by the function will be returned; use "outer apply" for functionality similar to left outer joins.

Comment: cross apply kills the performace when dealing with huge data. Is there any alternate for it?

Comment: No one answer to this. Some sound bites: (1) Identify the functionality performed by the called query and work it directly into the query. (2) Multi-statement table value functions (if there's a begin/end block) can be particularly horrible, avoid them at all costs. (3) Break the query into a series of queries, possibly populating temp tables along the way.

Comment: this "cross apply" could be disabled on SQL SERVER 2005 ?! I'm trying to do it and all I get is "Incorrect syntax near '.'"

Comment: CROSS and OUTER APPLY were added in SQL Server 2005, so you probably have some form of syntax error. Post it as a new question and it's sure to be answered very quickly.

Comment: I have experience the same issue as  @lucasvscn in SQL 2005. I think it might be a compatibility mode issue.