# SQL Server call a function with parameters taken from a table

Tags: sql-server, function, foreach

In a function I have a temporary table variable

```
DECLARE  TABLE 
(
   d DATE   
)
```

which contains some sorted dates:

```
DDate
2016-06-15
2016-05-11
2016-04-15
2016-03-15
2016-02-16
2016-01-14
```

I have to call a table-valued function

```
MyCompare(d1 DATE, d2 DATE)
```

in a loop for each pair (d, next d) until the returned table is empty. The function returns the current value of d.
How can I achieve it?

Comment: SQL doesn't need loops. Just write a `SELECT` statement, the same way you do with any other function. If you want a TVF to get parameters from another table, use INNER JOIN or CROSS APPLY.

Comment: I know it is Table value function `MyCompare(d1 DATE, d2 DATE)` really it returns table

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to join a table valued function and another table with parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916783/is-it-possible-to-join-a-table-valued-function-and-another-table-with-parameters)

Comment: Then use CROSS APPLY. You don't need a loop

Comment: Can you add sample data and the output you would expect that sample to return?  SO has a [guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that you might find useful.

Comment: there is no such thing as a table which contains some sorted dates

Comment: Show your current code and what error you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use query like this, add WHERE clause with condition you want to check on the function return data

```
DECLARE @t TABLE 
(
   d DATE   
)
INSERT INTO @t
VALUES
('2016-06-15')
,('2016-05-11')
,('2016-04-15')
,('2016-03-15')
,('2016-02-16')
,('2016-01-14')

SELECT t.*,fn.*
FROM
    ( 
        SELECT *,
            LEAD(d) OVER (ORDER BY d ) as NextDate
        FROM @t 
    ) AS t
OUTER APPLY dbo.MyCompare(d, NextDate ) as fn
--WHERE fn.columnname IS NOT NULL
```

LEAD analytical function works with SQL Server 2012 or later. If you are using earlier versions try below.

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY d ) AS RowNo 
    FROM @t
)

SELECT c.d, c1.d AS NextDate, fn.*
FROM CTE c
LEFT JOIN CTE c1 ON c1.RowNo = c.RowNo + 1
OUTER APPLY dbo.MyCompare(c.d, c1.d ) as fn
--WHERE fn.columnname IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: 'LEAD' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: which sql-server version are you using ?